# From GPT to MBR in linux ?

Tags: 16.04, windows, format, mbr

Actually I have ubuntu 16.04 in single boot but considering I'll have to install windiows 7 to be dual boot for work purposes , I could make a space for it using **GParted** but how can I format that space as **MBR** I can't find a way even googling it any help please ?

Comment: MBR and GPT are **disk** partition tables, and can't reside together at the same time on a single disk. Why do you think you need MBR? UEFI and GPT normally go hand in hand. Won't Windows 7 install in UEFI mode on a GPT disk?

Comment: Windows 7 default install is BIOS/MBR. But you can copy DVD to flash drive & move some files around to make it UEFI boot. Otherwise you have to totally redo drive. You may be able to use gdisk to convert, but may have partition issues. Windows in BIOS mode only installs to primary partitions and your conversion will probably use all of them, so even more work required. Easier to just install Windows in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 1):

`gdisk` has a `h` command that creates an MBR along with an existing GPT:

```
h   Create a hybrid MBR. This is an ugly workaround that enables
    GPT-unaware OSes, or those that can't boot from a GPT disk, to
    access up to three of the partitions on the disk by creating MBR
    entries for them. Note that these hybrid MBR entries can easily
    go out of sync with the GPT entries, particularly when
    hybrid-unaware GPT utilities are used to edit the disk. Thus,
    you may need to recreate the hybrid MBR if you use such tools.
    Unlike the 'g' option, this option does not support converting
    any partitions into MBR logical partitions.
```

Of course:

- the GPT prevails and the MBR is just an image which must be updated each time the GPT changes.
- the MBR won't be created from an incompatible GPT (partitions too large, too many partitions, etc)
- use it with caution! Backup your data before fiddling with the disc partitions